# HTML/CSS/JS content scrollbar under fixed div

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, fixed

Hi my question is can somebody help me to become the scrollbar of my content over the footer.

[How it looks on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnQOK.png)

And here code snippets

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="major">
        <div class="torso">
        <div id="gallery">
        </div>
        <div class="bone">
            <div class="aero">
                Menu
            </div>
            <div class="magneticaero">
                <a href="index.html" class="geo">
                    <div class="chest">
                        <div class="flaticon-house158">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html,head,body,p,div,a,ul,h2{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif,Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic;
text-decoration: none;}

.major{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: fixed;}

.torso{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow-y: scroll;}

.bone{
width: 100%;
height: 70px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: fixed;
background-color: #C2C2C2;
text-align: center;
transition: 1s;}

.aero{
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFF;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;}

.magneticareo{
width: 100%;
height: 360px;}

.chest{
width: 25%;
height: 350px;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #FFF;
float: left;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;}

.boneup{
height: 350px;}

.photo{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;}

.order{
width: 20%;
height: auto;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: left;}
```

[The solution i search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER61V.jpg)

I'd be really thankful when somebody could help me :-)
Tim

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to become the scrollbar over the footer on the first picture you see an arrow and i want that the scrollbar is there where the arrow points to. Sorry for grammer faults i hope you understand everything

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali i added a new picture at the end maybe that helps you to understand my probelm. I want that it looks like on the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `.aero` OUT of all the other elements, move it down directly above `</body>`, and give it a fixed position with `bottom: 0`

I addition, set the height of `.major` to `calc(100% - 40px)` , i.e. as high as the window minus the height of `.aero`. (And use `box-sizing: border-box`  on it to really only make it 40px high.)

ADDITION after seeing website: Assign `height: calc(100% - 70px);` to `.torso-gallery` - this has the same effect I described above and you won't need to change your HTML structure anymore.

Comment: Sadly that didnt worked for me the scrollbar is still at the wrong place

Comment: do you have that site on a server where we can see it?

Comment: I uploaded everything on a test site: https://profiletestsite.000webhostapp.com/gallery.html

Comment: You didn't move `.aero` out of `.major` - it's still inside it. But anyway, if you you assign `height: calc(100% - 70px);` to `.torso-gallery`, it has the same effect and your scrollbar ends above the footer.  (I'll add that to my answer)

Comment: Now it worked perfectly thank you very much Johannes